# How to set a datagridview values to it's datasource

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to pass `datasource` of a `datagridview` to another `Form`,

this is how i do that:

```
private void RationSummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RationReportFrm RRFrm = new 
    RationReportFrm(HomeDetailsdgv.DataSource, RationFormulationdgv;

    RRFrm.ShowDialog();
}
```

and

```
public RationReportFrm(object RationTotalds, object HomeTotalds)
{
    InitializeComponent();


    AnimalPerformancedgv.DataSource = RationTotalds;
    ProteinValuedgv.DataSource = HomeTotalds;
 }
```

now the question is:

`datasource` of one of these `datagridviews` has set by a `datatable` and it passes to `RationReportFrm` without any problem,
but one of them dosen't have any `datasource` and it's cells filled programmatically, How should I set it's cells values to it `datasource` in order to pass it to another form?

Comment: For the gridview that dosen't have any datasource, don't fill the datagrid view cells directly, but create a DataTable with the cells values and bind the DataGridview to the DataTable. *Note: for "null" values, use DBNull.Value in the DataTable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the beset way is to make a method to convert `datagridview` to a `datatable`

```
private DataTable GetDTFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (column.Visible)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add();
            if (column.Name != "")
            {
                dt.Columns[column.Index].ColumnName = column.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    object[] CellValue = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            CellValue[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(CellValue);
    }

    return dt;
}
```